# F# -> Seq to Map

Tags: f#

I'm trying to load all my `Categories` from the database and then map them to a `Map` (dictionary?), however when I use the following code:

```
[<StructuralComparison>]
type Category = { 
    mutable Id: string; 
    Name: string; 
    SavePath: string;
    Tags: ResizeArray<Tag> }

let categories = session.Query<Category>() 
                    |> Seq.map(fun z -> (z,0)) 
                    |> Map.ofSeq
```

it simply throws an error that says:

> The struct, record or union type
>   'Category' has the
>   'StructuralComparison' attribute but
>   the component type 'ResizeArray'
>   does not satisfy the 'comparison'
>   constraint

I have absolutely no clue about what to do, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

F# is rightly complaining that `ResizeArray<_>` doesn't support structural comparison.  `ResizeArray<_>` instances are mutable and don't support structural comparison, and you therefore can't use them as fields of records which are used as keys to `Map<_,_>`s (which are sorted by key).  You have a few options:

1. Have `Tags` use a collection type that does support structural comparison (such as an immutable `Tag list`).
2. Use `[<CustomComparison>]` instead of `[<StructuralComparison>]`, which requires implementing `IComparable`.
3. Use a mutable dictionary (or another relevant collection type) instead of a `Map`.  Try using the `dict` function instead of `Map.ofSeq`, for instance.

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that by adding `StructuralComparison` attribute to the type `Category` you've asked F# to use structural comparison when comparing instances of `Category`.  In short it will compare every member individually to see if they are equal to determine if two instances of `Category` are equal.

This puts an implicit constraint on every member of `Category` to themselves be comparable.  The type `ResizeArray<Tag>` is generating an error because it's not comparable.  This is true for most collection types.

In order to get rid of this error you'll need to make the `ResizeArray<T>` type comparable or choose a different key for the `Map`.  Don has a great blog post that goes into this topic in depth and provides a number of different ways to achieve this.  It's very much worth the read

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2009/11/08/equality-and-comparison-constraints-in-f-1-9-7.aspx